# Using crypto++ library with MSVS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, static-libraries, header-files, crypto++

I've downloaded Crypto++ library which contains cryptopp.dll and cryptopp.lib files. But I don't know how to use them in my project. I've tried to add cryptopp.lib to linker and cryptopp.dll to exe file directory but it didn't helped. There's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "cryptopp.lib)

using namespace CryptoPP;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

And it gives me this error:

```
error C2871: 'CryptoPP' : a namespace with this name does not exist
```

What I have to do to be able to use this library?

Comment: You have to include applicable headers, for example `#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>` assuming you have the path to the crypto++ headers in your include path.

Comment: Also see [Visual Studio](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio) on the Crypto++ wiki. You need to learn how to include headers and libraries under Visual Studio, just like with Eclipse or Xcode. You should also visit [FIPS DLL](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Fips_dll), and avoid it if possible. If you are having trouble with a static lib, then you definitely don't want to venture into the FIPS DLL.